# Need help validating

Tags: json, azure, visual-studio-code, cloud

```
{
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
   "parameters":{
      "webAppName":{
         "type":"string",
         "defaultValue":"[concat('webApp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
         "metadata":{
            "description":"Web app name."
         },
         "minLength":2
      },
      "location":{
         "type":"string",
         "defaultValue":"[resourceGroup().location]",
         "metadata":{
            "description":"Location for all resources."
         }
      },
      "sku":{
         "type":"string",
         "defaultValue":"F1",
         "metadata":{
            "description":"The SKU of App Service Plan."
         }
      },
      "variables":{
         "appServicePlanPortalName":"[concat('AppServicePlan-', parameters('webAppName'))]"
      },
      "resources":[
         {
            "apiVersion":"2019-08-01",
            "type":"Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "name":"[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
            "location":"[parameters('location')]",
            "sku":{
               "name":"[parameters('sku')]"
            }
         },
         {
            "apiVersion":"2019-08-01",
            "type":"Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "name":"[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "location":"[parameters('location')]",
            "properties":{
               "serverFarmId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn":[
               "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "outputs":{
         
      }  
   }
```

Comment: You are joking right?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What you posted is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one curly bracket at the end. You can check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/